How to identify what causes 100% CPU load in one thread?
I noticed that my laptop is constantly running the fan pretty loudly. When checking the CPU load with htop, it seems that no process is actually using a lot of CPU. However, there is still one Thread (no 7 in the screenshot) that is constantly used 100%. How can I identify what causes this high load?
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on a Tuxedo laptop with Intel Core i5-10210Ux8.


Gnome shell is a single threaded beast and thrashing is common.
